# how do I force the stroke-width of my svg with javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, width, stroke

I am trying to do an svg animation for a friend and, for it, I scaled some lines and circles (with svgator.com):

- When the scale of the stroke is about 0%, the stroke is really thin.
- When the scale of the stroke is about 100%, the stroke is really thick.

I would like the stroke width to remain the same all along.
I tried with css but it doesn't work.
I am thinking of javascript but know very knowledgeable and didn't find something that I could use.
I would really much appreciate your help.

My animation is currently here – sorry, it is not a pretty job but it does work:

```
https://krispykrush.com/ouiouioui4.svg
```

Thank you a lot,
marie

Comment: Use `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"` ()presentational attribute) or `vector-effect:non-scaling-stroke`in CSS

Comment: Thank you very much for the clue :)